# Source map from two file in grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I have two file say f1.js and f2.js .I concat these file through grunt-contrib-concat    say f3.js is generated after that I minify f3.js(newly generated file) by grunt-contrib-ugify   with  sourceMap option set to true .Is there any way by which  sourceMap file of f3 point to f1 and f2 ? So that when any error came on file f3 then on debugger i got exact location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the initial `grunt-contrib-concat` step in your workflow. `grunt-contrib-uglify` accepts an `Array` of source files (`f1.js` and `f2.js`) and it will concatenate to one file (`f3.js`). If the `sourceMap` option is enabled you'll get them.